# Assigning Variables to a Value in a Multivariable Function

Tags: functions, warning-messages

I wrote a function defined as so:

```
f[x_, y_] := (y)*(x^3) + x*y^2 - .1281
```

But when I try to assign `x` and `y` to numbers using `=`, I get an error saying that the numbers are not a proper variable, and then when I try to calculate

```
D[f[x, y], x]
```

I get a strange answer: $\frac{\partial 107.872}{\partial 3}$

I am new to Mathematica and I am not sure what I am doing wrong. How can I assign values to x and y and how will I be able to keep reassigning values to x and y within a loop every time the loop runs?

Comment: Quite probably you already assigned a value. Try to clear the variables or start with the a fresh kernel.

Answer (score 1):

```
x = 3.; y = 2.;
f[x_, y_] := y x^3 + x y^2 - .1281

D[f[x, y], x]
```

[image: msg]

> `D[65.8719, 3.]`

The problem is the arguments of `D` are being evaluated before `D` sees them. There is a function, [`Block`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Block.html) that can prevent that.

```
Block[{x, y}, D[f[x, y], x]]
```

> `58.`

The differentiation was done symbolically; the values of `x` and `y` were substituted after the differentiation, so the result is correct.

In a loop you will want the symbolic form of `D[f[x, y], x]`. `Block` can help you there, too.

```
Block[{x, y}, df[x_, y_] = D[f[x, y], x]]
```

> `58.`

But `df` is now a function that you can call like `f`.

```
df[u, v]
```

> `3 u^2 v + v^2`